# Program spins during multicast

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, thread-safety, multicast

The following program, ends up in a spin loop. I have no idea what might be the reason. I would be more than happy if someone could help me. In the following code, I have a sender which multicasts some data to the receivers of the group `224.0.1.20:64`. The sender waits for `val` variable of object `r` and `r1` of `ThreadManager` class, to send the data. And it closes after waiting for the `val1` of the same instances to change before exiting. I have tried `join()`, before. But it didn't work either. As shown below, the sender waits for Sometimes the code executes correctly giving the output, but some other times it just loops.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Sender s = new Sender(64);
        ThreadManager r = new ThreadManager();
        ThreadManager r1 = new ThreadManager();
        r.start();
        r1.start();
        //Thread.currentThread().setPriority(1);
        while(r.val1 != true || r1.val1 != true){
                    >// I know this is wrong way to wait, but this is just a test
                    >// appln, so I used polling.
            //Thread.currentThread().sleep(1);
            //System.out.println(r.val1 || r1.val1);
        }
        System.out.println("going to send..");
        s.send("kaushik");
        while((r.val != true || r1.val != true) || (r.isAlive() && r1.isAlive())){
                    // same here..
            System.out.println(r.val || r.val1);
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("closing..");

    }
}
class ThreadManager extends Thread{
    public boolean val = false;
    public boolean val1  = false;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Reciever r;
        try {
            r = new Reciever(64);

            byte[] buf = new byte[65508];
            System.out.println("Going. to be started...");
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, 65508);  
  val1 = true;

            r.recieve(packet);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            val = true;
            System.out.println(val+" Id :"+Thread.currentThread().getId());


    }

}
class Sender{
    private MulticastSocket s;
    public Sender(int port) throws IOException{
        s = new MulticastSocket(port);
        s.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("224.0.1.20"));
    }
    public void send(String data) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Server"+s.getLocalPort());
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.getBytes().length,InetAddress.getByName("224.0.1.20"),s.getLocalPort());
        s.send(packet);
        System.out.println("server"+s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        s.close();
    }
}
class Reciever{
    private MulticastSocket s;
    public Reciever(int port) throws IOException{
        s = new MulticastSocket(port);
        s.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("224.0.1.20"));
    }
    public void recieve(DatagramPacket packet) throws IOException{
        s.receive(packet);
        byte recv[] = new byte[65508];
        System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), 0, recv, 0, packet.getData().length);
        //System.out.println(new String(recv));
        System.out.println(new String(recv).trim() + "Date : "+ new Date() + "length :" +new String(recv).trim().length());
        s.leaveGroup(InetAddress.getByName("224.0.1.20"));
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Output:
1.
Going. to be started...
Going. to be started...
going to send..
Server64
servernull
kaushikDate : Wed Nov 26 11:19:09 EST 2014length :7
true Id :9
kaushikDate : Wed Nov 26 11:19:09 EST 2014length :7
true Id :10

** pls see that, I'm setting val1 and val to true in the ThreadManager class**. In the above output, val1 was set true for both r1 and r instances, but still the program is not terminating.

Comment: It's not a deadlock. It is ***blocked,*** in `receive()`. A deadlock occurs when you have a circular resource-claiming pattern. No such thing here.

Comment: @EJP: Sometimes "going to send.." this line is not getting printed which clearly points that there is a deadlock. Basically, before even the s.send("kaushik"); call, is called, the deadlock is occurring..

Comment: Not getting to some line of code does not 'clearly indicate a deadlock'. It could be many other things. You are misusing this term. Look it up. If you still think it's a deadlock please tell us which two or more lockable resources are involved.

Comment: @EJP: I'm setting val and val1 to true, in ThreadManager class.

Comment: @EJP: Then why do you think, that the program is not exiting. From, the output that I have attached, both the reciever has recieved 'kaushik' and both the reciever has set val1 = true but still the server is not ending because of which the program is not terminating. Dont you think this one to be a deadlock. Because, the sender is waiting for some change, to happen and this change is not reflected. I think atomic access is violated. That is only reason i can think of..

Comment: Because "You have a loop prior to the line that isn't reached. The loop never exits because the loop condition remains true ... the variables you are testing in the prior loop don't assume the exit values." I told you that yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not deadlock. [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is Unreliable, if your packs lost in the way, the Reciever will wait for data, and that looks like "deadlock". it's better to set a "timeout" for Reciever.

here you share r.val1 to main thread, you need "[volatile](https://blog.thesoftwarecraft.com/2014/07/javas-volatile-modifier.html)" to let val1 visible immediately to main thread when its value changed, volatile also prevent aggressive optimization from JIT or CPU.

```
public volatile boolean val1  = false;
```

be careful of using synchronized here, synchronized(this) doesn't work because that means synchronized(r) and synchronized(r1), those are different "lock"s. if you want to protect shared variables across threads, please use the same "lock".

Comment: Sometimes **"going to send.."** this line is not getting printed which clearly points that there is a deadlock. Basically, before even the **s.send("kaushik");** call, is called, the deadlock is occurring..

Comment: @KaushikSivaprasad No it doesn't, it indicates that the variables you are testing in the prior loop don't assume the exit values.

Comment: @EJP: can u elaborate further. Thanx in advance.

Comment: try add modifier "volatile" to val1.

Comment: @KaushikSivaprasad You have a loop prior to the line that isn't reached. The loop never exits because the loop condition remains true. That is not a deadlock.

Comment: @KaushikSivaprasad make sure you use jdk 1.6 or above so that volatile works correctly, add a print stat after "val1 = true;" ensure val1 is set to true.

Comment: @mysh: I tried with volatile. Now its working. Thanks. Before there was a small bug, in my code. I had commented by mistake, the code that will make the reciever to join the group.

Comment: @mysh: I tried with synchronized(this){val1 = true;} and synchronized(this){val = true;}. Why didnt that one work.

Comment: @mysh: and from the documentation, all the primitive datatypes except double and long have atomic read and write.  [Atomic access reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

Comment: @KaushikSivaprasad something about [volatile](https://blog.thesoftwarecraft.com/2014/07/javas-volatile-modifier.html). atomic access doesn't means thread's variable value changes  are visible immediately across threads.

Comment: @mysh: understood.. So u mean to say that, for variables that may be modified across multiple threads, it is good to use volatile. But wat is strange is that, i have never encountered such an issue when i had to develop shared access variable across threads. But what is strange is that i used synchronized(this){val = true;}.. Even this one is not reflecting the change in sender thread..

Comment: @KaushikSivaprasad about the synchronized, posted in the answer.